# VNC File transfer between Windows server and Linux client

Tags: linux, vnc, clipboard, tightvnc, vnc-viewer

I have TightVNC Server installed on a **Windows 7** machine, with file transfers option enabled.
[image: TightVNC server configuration]

I remotely connet to that machine from a **Ubuntu 20.04** machine, using a VNC client.

I am able to copy/paste text between the two machines, but not files.

I have tried with following VNC clients with no success: TigerVNC, Remmina and xtightvncviewer

Is ther any way to copy/paste files between the two machines?

Answer (score 0):

This featuere is available for Windows to Windows only, according to this [SE post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/12491)